# VB SQL CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to working with background workers, and I'm trying to run the following code. But I recieve a run-time error on the `m._Value_CreatedDate = m._MyCMD.ExecuteScalar()` line. The error is:

> Additional information: ExecuteScalar: CommandText property has not
>   been initialized

```
        Try
            Dim m As MyParameters = DirectCast(e.Argument, MyParameters) 
            m._Con.Open()
            m._QueryStr = "SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(10),aCreated,103) FROM Account WHERE aMember_ID = " & m._Selected_MemberID & ""
            m._MyCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            m._Value_CreatedDate = m._MyCMD.ExecuteScalar()
        Catch ex As Exception
            m._Value_CreatedDate = "N/A"
        End Try
```

Here's the Parameter's I'm using:

```
 Class MyParameters
        Friend _QueryStr As String
        Friend _Value_CreatedDate As Object
        Friend _AccountID As Object
        Friend _Selected_MemberID As String = Committee_Database.GridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Unique ID").ToString
        Friend _Con As New SqlConnection('Connection string ommitted)
        Friend _MyCMD As New SqlCommand(_QueryStr, _Con)
    End Class
```

Please forgive me if I'm doing something extremely wrong, I'm self taught and experimenting with the `backgroundworker`. It's worth noting that `_QueryStr` will change multiple times as the background worker runs multiple queries against the same database and (as I understand it) stores each of the returned values from the queries into variables - `_Value_CreatedDate` is the variable I am using in this code. I've included an example of how I'm recycling the `_QueryStr` variable below and storing the returned value into a diffent Variable each time.

```
            Try
            m._QueryStr = "SELECT TOP 1 aAccount_ID FROM Account WHERE aUser_Name='" & _Selected_AccountID & "'"
            m._MyCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            m._AccountID = m._MyCMD.ExecuteScalar()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the implementation of your class `MyParameters` you initialize the SqlCommand directly with the declaration using the value of the variable _QueryStr. At that point in time the variable _QueryStr is not yet initialized, so it is an empty string.

After the initialization of an instance of `MyParameters`, you change the value of `_QueryStr` (many times according to you) but these changes are not automatically passed to the CommandText of your SqlCommand. It still contains the empty initial value.

You could fix this problem building appropriate getter and setter for a new `QueryStr` property. When someone tries to set the property the code below change the value of the internal field _QueryStr (now private) and reinitializes the CommandText property of your SqlCommand.

```
Class MyParameters
   Private _QueryStr As String
   Public Property QueryStr() As String
      Get
         Return _QueryStr
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _QueryStr = value
        _MyCMD.CommandText = _QueryStr
    End Set
    End Property
    ..... other properties
    Friend _MyCMD As New SqlCommand(_QueryStr, _Con)
End Class
```

Now when you write

```
Try
   m.QueryStr = "SELECT ...."
   ....
```

the new command text is correctly assigned to your command.

As a side note: I suggest to use plain ADO.NET objects (or learn how to use an ORM tool). Do not try to encapsulate them in custom classes unless you have a very deep understanding on how these ADO.NET objects works. You gain nothing and expose your code to many problems. For example your code is very easy to exploit with [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) because the MyParameters class has no provision to use a parameterized query. Your code has no method to close and dispose the SqlConnection embedded in your class thus leading to resource leaks.

Comment: Actually my problem is different but that answer gave me idea to catch my error. I used Asynchronus DataReader to fetch data and my old code even **change the CommandText directly** it changes on wrong place. Changes between producing Task variable and await operation. All changes SqlCommand properties did not reflect the Task operation. I cant believe this bug consumes  all my day and thanks for helping solve this bug.